# randint returns same number over and over

Tags: python-3.x, random

I'm just getting started with Python, and ran into a problem. I'm writing a function to simulate a coin flip. 
When I wrote some mock code to test the randint function it worked perfectly fine and returned a nice random sequence of heads and tails. The code I try to use in my program however returns only h's or t's.

```
import random

coin_sequence = "hhththththhhhttthht"
generated_sequence = "" #define generated_sequence
length = len(coin_sequence)
flip = random.randint(0, 1)
for value in range(length):
    if flip == 0:
        generated_sequence = generated_sequence + "t"
    else:
        generated_sequence = generated_sequence + "h"

print(generated_sequence)
```

I probably made some really stupid mistake. Who can help me?

Comment: `randint()` is only asked **once** to produce a number. You then check that same number again and again.

Comment: You're caching the return value of `randint` once so it never regenerates a new number. You must call it again to get a new number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `random.randint()` **once**, before the loop starts:

```
flip = random.randint(0, 1)
for value in range(length):
    # ...
```

That call returns an integer object. Checking that integer again and again in a loop won't change its value, no matter what function produced it originally.

If you wanted to get new random numbers, ask `random.randint()` to produce one *in the loop*:

```
for value in range(length):
    flip = random.randint(0, 1)
    if flip == 0:
        generated_sequence = generated_sequence + "t"
    else:
        generated_sequence = generated_sequence + "h"
```

Note that you could write that loop a little more concisely with:

```
for value in range(length):
    flip = random.randint(0, 1)
    generated_sequence += "t" if flip == 0 else "h"
```